# working with master and develop branch in Azure DevOps, avoiding the 1 ahead and 1 behind state of master

Tags: git, azure

We have an Azure DevOps repo with 2 remote branches: master and develop.

The develop branch is marked as the "Default" branch and also the "Compare" branch.

I have today completed a pull request to the remote "develop" branch from a local branch called ajf2 but I allowed this action to delete my local ajf2 branch (as per default of Azure DevOps). 
The change is only a change to one file.

We are now keen to update the remote master branch.

The last time we did a pull direct from the remote develop to the remote master branch but this left the master branch with a 1 behind and 1 ahead status and an admin person then did a branch delete and recreate on the develop branch to resolve this 1 behind and 1 ahead status.

I have a strong feeling I was meant to pull from local ajf2 branch to master and then from ajf2 to develop before allowing local ajf2 branch to be deleted?

Maybe we shouldn't worry about the 1 behind 1 ahead type of status indication on master branch on Azure DevOps?

I have had a review of this article:

https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/git-branching-strategies/gitflow-examples/

Am wondering what steps we can take from here, this time, to avoid the 1 behind and 1 ahead status that occurred last time we pulled directly from remote develop branch to remote master branch. I guess we could regard the master as now requiring a "hot fix" ?  I don't have access to mark the master branch as the default branch.

Fun with Git branches and repos !

I would like to learn the correct steps for working with both develop and master branch and local branches and avoiding this 1 behind and 1 ahead branch status on master.

Any advice / answers much appreciated !

Comment: Am thinking that the GIT "Behind | Ahead" numbers and indication are of little consequence ... what matters is the branch content ... If the branches contents match and the "Behind | Ahead" have non zero values then no concern should really occur .. (?) ..

Comment: The Windows tool called WinMerge is a great tool to compare entire file structure content.